# ASIFormDataRequest: POST both image/jpeg and application/xml with a

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, http

Given both:

```
NSData *jpegData;
NSString *xmlPost:
```

How do I construct an ASIFormDataRequest to post both the image/jpeg data and the applicaton/xml data as a multipart/mixed POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that I'm not actually answering about your question.

Two facts.

1. The `ASIFormDataRequest` class is not designed to support 'multipart/mixed'. (at least, currently)
2. XML is just a plain string which can be sent via `multipart/form-data` too.

If your situation is forcing you have to use `multipart/mixed`, just ignore me. (for instance, your client don't want to modifying server program which support only `multipart/mixed`.)

If not, please think again once. Do you really need the `multipart/mixed` itself? No choice? Never 'multipart/form-data'? As I know, most server part programmers like 'multipart/form-data' more than other rarely used format because it supported by most server frameworks. So it makes their life a lot easier :)

If you really want another 'regularity' or 'efficiency' or some other specials instead of simplicity, you should consider other than HTTP. The only benefits of HTTP is stability and compatibility. (from it's well-defined specification and long history) This is most important benefits, but may not suitable for you.

I didn't try 'multipart/mixed'. Maybe it's possible someone has a simple way to do this.
But basically this is a kind of hacking job. (enabling feature which absent on original design) This should be painful. It'll be easier making your own class from the HTTP specification.

I strongly recommend you to use `multipart/form-data` instead of. Which is supported on the class by design. You can assume an XML source just like a plain string. Which can be sent via plain POST field value.